# Move only class parameter in inherited constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, move-semantics

The following code doesn't compile [`GCC 6.1`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5281d63ac12d5c9), but works in [`Clang 3.8.0`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65b46bd5b6b6a0bb) and [`Visual Studio 2015`](http://rextester.com):

```
#include <memory>

class base {
public:
    base(std::unique_ptr<int>) {}
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    using base::base;
};

int main() {
    derived df(std::make_unique<int>());
}
```

With the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'derived::derived(std::unique_ptr<int>)':

main.cpp:10:17: error: use of deleted function 
'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) 
[with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'

     using base::base;

                 ^~~~

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/memory:81:0,

                 from main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/include/c++/6.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:356:7: note: declared here

       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

       ^~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:14:39: note: synthesized method 'derived::derived(std::unique_ptr<int>)' 
first required here 

     derived df(std::make_unique<int>());
```

It appears to be trying to call the deleted copy constructor, but this works just fine:

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int>) {}

int main() {
    foo(std::make_unique<int>());
}
```

And this example with `-fno-elide-constructors` prints out `move called.`:

```
struct move_only {
    move_only() { std::cout << "default called."; }
    move_only(move_only&&) { std::cout << "move called."; }
};

void foo(move_only) { }

int main() {
    foo(move_only{});
}
```

I realize the two situations are not identical but it seems strange that `&&` is required to make the inherited constructor example compile but not the latter. As a sanity check, explicitly doing `move_only(const move_only&) = delete;` and changing the signature to `void foo(const move_only&) { }` still compiles, except this time the move constructor is not even called (elision perhaps).

[12.6.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.inhctor.init#initialization!by~inherited~constructor) of the latest draft standard says:

> 1 When a constructor for type `B` is invoked to initialize an object
>   of a different type `D` (that is, when the constructor was inherited
>   ([namespace.udecl])), initialization proceeds as if a defaulted
>   default constructor were used to initialize the D object and each base
>   class subobject from which the constructor was inherited, except that
>   the B subobject is initialized by the invocation of the inherited
>   constructor. The complete initialization is considered to be a single
>   function call; in particular, the initialization of the inherited
>   constructor's parameters is sequenced before the initialization of any
>   part of the `D` object. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct B1 {
>   B1(int, ...) { }
> };
>
> // ...
>
> struct D1 : B1 {
>   using B1::B1;  // inherits B1(int, ...)
>   int x;
>   // ...
> };
>
> void test() {
>   D1 d(2, 3, 4); // OK: B1 is initialized by calling B1(2, 3, 4),
>                  // then d.x is default-initialized (no initialization is performed),
>   // ...
> }
>
> // ...
> ```

So it should be exactly equivalent to `foo(move_only)` right?

Comment: Inheriting constructor semantics underwent [a giant overhaul](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html) in the current working draft; nobody has implemented the new version yet.

Comment: It looks like a regression in g++ 6.1. [It compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/d9PaA8) in g++5.3

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug (reported as [bug 70972](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70972)). N4140 [class.inhctor]/8:

> An implicitly-defined inheriting constructor performs the set of
>   initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written
>   inline constructor for that class with a *mem-initializer-list* whose
>   only *mem-initializer* has a *mem-initializer-id* that names the base
>   class denoted in the *nested-name-specifier* of the *using-declaration*
>   and an *expression-list* as specified below, and where the
>   *compound-statement* in its function body is empty (12.6.2). If that
>   user-written constructor would be ill-formed, the program is
>   ill-formed. Each *expression* in the *expression-list* is of the form
>   `static_cast<T&&>(p)`, where `p` is the name of the corresponding
>   constructor parameter and `T` is the declared type of `p`.

In other words, the inheriting constructor at issue here should be moving, not copying, its parameter.